# Angular File upload with multiple filters

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

I'm trying to put 2 different filters one is the file type the other is the size of the files. Currently I'm using this:

```
uploader.filters.push({
        name: 'imageFilter',
        fn: function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
            var type = '|' + item.type.slice(item.type.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + '|';
            return '|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif|'.indexOf(type) !== -1;
        }
    });
```

How can I add a second filter to this uploader that limits file size to 600x600px?

UPDATE 1:
I wanted to check for file type AND file size.
it figured it out:

```
uploader.filters.push({
        name: 'imageFilter',
        fn: function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
            var type = '|' + item.type.slice(item.type.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + '|';
            return '|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif|'.indexOf(type) !== -1;
        },
        name:'sizeFilter',
        fn: function(item, options){
            console.log(item);
            var maxSize=360000;
            console.log(item.size+":"+maxSize+" : "+(parseInt(item.size) >= maxSize));
            return parseInt(item.size) >= maxSize; 
        }
    });
```

now this does not actually give me the size of the actual image (if it is really wide but only 100px high it may still hit that file size).

Comment: Is the second argument of your function the actual file itself?

Comment: to be honest: this is copypaste of the examples

Comment: Just use same as above then. Except for checking for the file type in the body of the function just check if the size of the file is greater than the limit you want to set.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but couldn't you just use something like

```
uploader.filters.push({
            name: 'sizeFilter',
            fn: function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
                return item.file.size > {the size you want to check here} 
            }
        });
```

Comment: I wanted to check for both file size and file type. see my update to the question above

Answer (score 0):

> Keep them as 2 different filters -

```
uploader.filters.push({
    name: 'imageFilter',
    fn: function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/ , options) {
        var type = '|' + item.type.slice(item.type.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + '|';
        return '|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif|'.indexOf(type) !== -1;
    }
});

uploader.filters.push({
    name: 'sizeFilter',
    fn: function(item, options) {
        console.log(item);
        var maxSize = 360000;
        console.log(item.size + ":" + maxSize + " : " + (parseInt(item.size) >= maxSize));
        return parseInt(item.size) >= maxSize;
    }
});
```

> Then, **just use them as** - `filters="imageFilter, sizeFilter"` in your html. ***That't it!***